# leading comma in param list implies empty parens?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

In VS2010, the following code compiles and runs in a .c file:

```
void F1(,a,b,c,d,e){}  // Note the leading comma.

void F2(void){
 int x = 10;
 void* y = 0;
 F1(x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, y);  // Compiles fine.
}
```

So it's effectively acting like this had been seen somewhere:

```
void F1();
```

The following code fails to compile with an unknown identifier error on the printf line for each param:

```
void F1(,a,b,c,d,e){
 printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c, d, e);
}
```

Is this part of the C standard?  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not standard behavior.  [File a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).  The C89 standard (draft version available [here](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt)) defines the syntax for a function definition to be (§3.7.1):

```
3.7.1 Function definitions

Syntax

          function-definition:
                  declaration-specifiers<opt> declarator
                            declaration-list<opt> compound-statement
```

And §3.5.4 defines a *declarator* to be:

```
3.5.4 Declarators

Syntax

          declarator:
                  pointer<opt> direct-declarator

          direct-declarator:
                  identifier
                  (  declarator ) 
                  direct-declarator [  constant-expression<opt> ] 

                  direct-declarator (  parameter-type-list ) 
                  direct-declarator (  identifier-list<opt> )

          pointer:
                  *  type-qualifier-list<opt>
                  *  type-qualifier-list<opt> pointer

          type-qualifier-list:
                  type-qualifier
                  type-qualifier-list type-qualifier

          parameter-type-list:
                  parameter-list
                  parameter-list , ...

          parameter-list:
                  parameter-declaration
                  parameter-list ,  parameter-declaration

          parameter-declaration:
                  declaration-specifiers declarator
                  declaration-specifiers abstract-declarator<opt>

          identifier-list:
                  identifier
                  identifier-list ,  identifier
```

In the case of the definition `void F1(,a,b,c,d,e){}`, `void` is a *declaration-specifier* and `F1(,a,b,c,d,e)` is (supposedly) the *declarator*.  Of the 5 possible alternatives for a *direct-declarator*, the only ones it can match are the last two.  But, the parenthesized subexpression `,a,b,c,d,e)` does not match either a *parameter-type-list* or a *identifier-list*, so it is an ill-formed expression.

Answer (score 3):

This is illegal C99: the parameter list **must** specify the types of the parameters; in C90 they default to `int`.

And, I think, it's also illegal in C99 because the text in [the Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (6.9.1) uses the "shall" form for parameter type list, and identifier list. *I assume the same is valid for C90 making the code illegal with that language too, for the same reason, but I can't check that now.*

> **6.9.1/5**
>   If the declarator includes a parameter type  list,  the
>          declaration  of  each parameter **shall** include an identifier,
>          except for the special case of a parameter  list  consisting
>          of  a  single  parameter  of  type void, in which case there
>          shall not be  an  identifier.   No  declaration  list  shall
>          follow.
>
> **6.9.1/6**
>   If  the  declarator  includes an identifier list, each
>          declaration in the declaration list **shall** have at least  one
>          declarator, those declarators shall declare only identifiers
>          from the  identifier  list,  and  every  identifier  in  the
>          identifier  list  shall be declared.  An identifier declared
>          as a typedef name shall not be redeclared  as  a  parameter.
>          The  declarations  in  the declaration list shall contain no
>          storage-class  specifier  other   than   register   and   no
>          initializations.

Comment: Visual Studio is not even close to being C99-compliant, nor does it claim to be.  It's C89 all the way.